# Authentication failed on Laravel Vapor CLI

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I just installed Laravel Vapor today and am so excited to get started, but I've run into a wall with authentication from my Mac (using iTerm). I enter `vapor login`, then follow the prompts for `Email Address:` and `Password:`... and get `Authentication failed.` every time. I have triple-checked my email address, very carefully entered the password, checked caps lock is not on, and changed my password 3 times via the website and re-entered to see if it changed anything. I don't know what else I can do! Has anyone else run into this problem?? Any suggestions??

Comment: In case it matters, I installed Vapor CLI globally.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of laravel/vapor-cli which is v1.2.7. This version shows more details when the login authentication fails.

In my case, there was a problem with the openssl/cert.pem. Once I installed the certificate, I was able to login to vapor. You can install this certificate by using

```
brew install openssl
```